# Invalid Path while inserting job from google cloud storage to google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to insert a job through HTTP Post request, but i am getting Invalid path error.

My request body is as follows:

```
{
"configuration": {
"load": {
"sourceUris": [
"gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv"
],
"schema": {
"fields": [
{
"name": "Name",
"type": "STRING"
},
{
"name": "Age",
"type": "INTEGER"
}
]
},
"destinationTable": {
"datasetId": "Test_Dataset",
"projectId": "lithe-anvil-404",
"tableId": "tb_test_Pers"
}
}
},
"jobReference": {
"jobId": "10",
"projectId": "lithe-anvil-404"
}
}
```

For the sourceuri parameter, I am passing "gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv", where onianalytics is my bucket name and PersData.csv is my csv file (from which I want to upload data into google bigquery).

I am getting below response:

```
"status": {
"state": "DONE",
"errorResult": {
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid path: gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv"
},
"errors": [
{
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid path: gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv"
}
]
},
"statistics": {
"creationTime": "1387276603674",
"startTime": "1387276603751",
"endTime": "1387276603751"
}
}
```

Please explain why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Is your bucket under the same projectId that has the BigQuery service activated and you requested tokens with? If not, have you tried enabling read/write access for that project?

Comment: Yes, my bucket is under the same projectid which has the BigQuery service activated. How can I enable read/write access for that project.

Comment: Are you including the
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
scope to view and manage your data across Google Cloud Platform when requesting tokens?

Comment: Yes, this scope is already included. In fact, I am inserting this job by "Try it!" link which is available on https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert. Following scopes are added: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only. Please help me out from this, I got stuck.

Comment: Strange. In your Google APIs Console, do you have Google Cloud Storage enabled under APIs and Auth?

Comment: yes, it is enabled. In fact I am able to create buckets and objects in goggle cloud storage through APIs. But when i try to insert job from the uploaded object (which is a csv file), i got "Invalid Path" error.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem!

Comment: I need to fix this error ASAP. Can anyone help me out to fix it?